# Como fazer uma consulta em linguagem C?

Tags: c, struct

Boa noite, estou fazendo um projetinho de escrever arquivos em binários em um txt e depois ler esses arquivos. Porém tenho que ler o arquivo ou listar todos. 
Como eu poderia fazer uma busca pelo arquivo necessário? E mais uma pergunta oque é o feof?
Lista o ultimo dado, eu queria listar por pesquisa, tipo digitar o nome e consultar.
1-Vamos supor que eu grave a música "In the end" do linkin park...e em seguida gravo outras músicas. Eu queria que quando eu apertasse em consultar,
eu digitasse o nome da musica no caso "In the end" e me retornasse os dados só da minha consulta

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct{
char nome[30];
char banda[40];
float valor;
}musica;

void escreveMusica()
{
 char numstr[8];

FILE *fptr;

if((fptr=fopen("Musicas","wb"))==NULL){

    printf("Não posso abrir arquivo...Musicas");//Caso nao consiga abrir
    exit(1);
}
do{
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n Digite o nome da musica: ");
    gets(musica.nome);
    printf("\n Digite o nome da banda: ");
    gets(musica.banda);
    printf("\n Digite o preco: ");
    gets(numstr);
    musica.valor=atof(numstr);
    fwrite(&musica,sizeof(musica),1,fptr);
    printf("\n Adiciona outro registro no arquivo..");
 }
while(getchar()=='s');
fclose(fptr);   
 }

void listarMusicas(){   
 char numstr[8];

FILE *fptr;
if((fptr=fopen("Musicas","rb"))==NULL){
    printf("Nao posso abrir arquivo... Musicas");
    exit(1);
}
printf("\nDados da consulta:\n");
while(fread(&musica, sizeof(musica),1,fptr)==1){//Pegar todas As     
listagens
    printf("\n Nome: %s\n",musica.nome);
    printf("\n Banda: %s\n",musica.banda);
    printf("\n Preco: %.2f\n",musica.valor);
    printf("\n--------------------\n");
}
fclose(fptr);       
           }

void consultarMusica(){ //Lista o ultimo dado, eu queria listar por
char numstr[8];             pesquisa, tipo digitar o nome e listar 

FILE *fptr;
if((fptr=fopen("Musicas","rb"))==NULL){
    printf("Nao posso abrir arquivo... Musicas");
    exit(1);
}
printf("\nDados da consulta:\n");

    printf("\n Nome: %s\n",musica.nome);
    printf("\n Banda: %s\n",musica.banda);
    printf("\n Preco: %.2f\n",musica.valor);
    printf("\n--------------------\n");

fclose(fptr);       
           }

int main()
{
int scan;

do{

printf("Selecione a opcao desejada\n1.Para comprar musica\n2.Para 
consultar todas as musicas compradas\n3.Consultar Ultima   
Musica\n0.Sair\n");
scanf("%d",&scan);

switch(scan){

case 1: escreveMusica();
system("cls");
break;
case 2: listarMusicas();
printf("\n");
break;
case 3: consultarMusica();
printf("\n");
break;
case 0: break;  
default: 
printf("Opcao Invalida");
}

}
while(scan!=0);

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está muito clara clique em **[Editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/169444/edit)** e descreva melhor o que você precisa. Como que tipo de busca você quer fazer, ou o que você quer buscar e aonde quer buscar.

Comment: pronto ja editei

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você que buscar dados no para uma consulta dentro de um arquivo, recomendo usar o `fwrite` e o `fread`, pois ele irá escrever os bytes exatos a sua estrutura, assim facilitando sua busca.

**Inserindo dados:**

```
typedef struct __musica{
    char nome[64];
    char banda[64];
    float valor;
}musica;
```

A estrutura musica possui um tamanho fixo, assim podendo ser visto com o `sizeof`

```
void inserir(musica *m, FILE *f){
    fwrite(m, sizeof(musica), 1, f); // escreve a estrutura no arquivo
}
```

**Buscando dados:**

```
musica *busca_p_nome(FILE *f, const char *nome){
    musica *m = malloc(sizeof(musica));
    fseek(f, SEEK_SET, 0); // vai até o inicio do arquivo
    while(!feof(f)){
        fread(m, sizeof(musica), 1, f); // le a estrutura do arquivo
        if(!strcmp(m->nome,nome)) // compara o nome da musica com o nome da musica desejada
             return m; // retorna a musica se encontrar
    }

    return NULL; // se não encontrar a musica retorna Nulo
}
```

Para inserir os as musicas sem apagar as já existentes, o arquivo deve conter o parâmetro `"a"` para ser aberto. `fopen("lista.txt", "a")`, o `a` representa *Append To File*.

O `feof` significa *End Of File* (a primeira letra representa que pertence aos método de arquivo, por isso feof), quando chega ao final do arquivo ele retorna `1`, coso contrario retorna `0`.

Por isso se usa `!feof(arquivo)` na condicional.

Comment: Ta, vamos la pode ser que resolva meu erro, porém quero entender o código, oque exatamente você fez em (File *f, const char *nome) Criou outro ponteiro? E se sim, pra que? Enquanto a linha *m = malloc(sizeof(musica)); pra que você precisa descobrir o tamanho? (fseek SEEK_SET, 0) não sei para que serve esses comandos poderia me dar uma breve explicação?

Comment: musica *busca_p_nome(FILE *f, const char *nome) eu criei um étodo que vai buscar a musica, FILE *f é o arquivo onde vai procurar e const char *nome representa qualquer texto que queira colocar.# *m = malloc - Está reservando um espaço na memória do tamanho da estrutura musica.# o fseek ande pelo arquivo, SEEK_SET diz que vai posicionar a partir do inicio do arquivo, e o do arquivo que deseja ir.

Comment: Ah, tudo certo, obrigado :D

Comment: Cara, outra coisa que me confundiu foi o typedef ter quase o mesmo nome tipo _musica e musica isso não muda em nada?

Comment: O typedef cria um apelido, se ficasse apenas struct musica, no código deveria escrever `struct musica` sempre, então eu coloquei um nome parecido e depois defini o apelido, ou sejá `musica` é igual a `struct __musica`

Comment: Eu sei que o typedef cria apelido, porém ficou confuso com aquele musica  depois das chaves da struct também, eu estou entrando em struct agora então não tenho muito conhecimento na parte de struct essa função inserir eu deveria chamar ela em que parte do código? e oque passar nos parametros dela?

Comment: a parte da struct não tem a necessidade de chamar em nenhum outro lugar, agora o método, os parametros são... o arquivo que você esta salvando os dados e um texto `"Let it be"` (o nome da musica).